# search for dates in excel worksheet and add one hour

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have a sheet where all dates are in the wrong timezone. I need to add one hour to all cells formated as dates, but leave the rest intact.

I found this:

```
Public Function AddHour(ByVal sTime As String) As String
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = CDate(sTime)
    dt = DateAdd("h", 1, dt)

    AddHour = Format(dt, "mm/dd/yy h:nnam/pm")

End Function
```

Now, how do I find the cells with dates in them?

`Sub AddHour(ByVal ThisSheet As Worksheet)`...

Comment: VBA has an `IsDate` function.  You might also need to use the `IsNumeric` function and/or check the cell format if there might be strings that look like dates, but you don't want to process them as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below was modified to apply additional information you provided in your comment below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddHour()
    ' 17 Dec 2017

    Const FirstColumn As String = "A"           ' set as required
    Const LastColumn As String = "AV"           ' set as required

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cf As Long, Cl As Long                  ' first / last column
    Dim Dt As Double
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last used row (in column C)
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    Set Ws = Worksheets("AddHour")              ' replace with your sheet's name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Ws
        Cf = Columns(FirstColumn).Column
        Cl = Columns(LastColumn).Column
        For C = Cf To Cl
            Application.StatusBar = Cl - C + 1 & " columns remaining"
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row
            For R = 1 To Rl                     ' start looking in row 1 (amend if necessary)
                With .Cells(R, C)
                    If IsDate(.Value) Then
                        Dt = .Value
                        ' add 1 hour if there is a Time value in the date
                        If Dt - Int(Dt) Then .Value = Dt + (1 / 24)
                    End If
                End With
            Next R
            Stop
        Next C
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With
End Sub
```

You still have to replace the worksheet name  "AddHour" in the code with whatever name your worksheet really has and specify the first and last columns where your dates are. You can change the first row in which the code starts looking for them.

The code presumes that your dates are "true" dates. You can test this by selecting any cell with a date you want to change and set its cell format temporarily to "General". If the date is a "true" date a number will be displayed instead of the date, like 43086.5046489583. If the display in the cell doesn't change upon reformatting then your dates are "Text" and must be treated differently.

Comment: I am trying your code, no joy yet. I got a sheet with "true" dates from A1:V191 currently but this is very dynamic. Also I got column E,F,T,V  at the moment but this might change and I need this to work even if this changes.

Comment: I modified the code above to implement your additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely certain, that all dates in your sheet have to be modified you could loop over all cells in your used range and make the adjustments using your function like so:

```
Sub ChangeDate()

    Dim rngDates As Range
    Dim varCounter As Variant
    Dim dt As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Set rngDates = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange

    'Loop over all cells in range
    For Each varCounter In rngDates
        'If it's a date, change its value
        If IsDate(varCounter.Value) Then
            dt = CDate(varCounter.Value)
            dt = DateAdd("h", 1, dt)
            varCounter.Value = Format(dt, "mm/dd/yy h:nnam/pm")
        End If

    Next varCounter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Depending on the amount of cells in your used range this might not be very performant.

To improve on that we can read your used range into an array and process it in memory like so:

```
Sub ChangeDate()

    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim lngColumns As Long, lngRows As Long
    Dim dt As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    'Read entire range to array
    varValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange

    'Loop over all "columns"
    For lngColumns = 1 To UBound(varValues, 1)
        'Loop over all "rows" in that "column"
        For lngRows = 1 To UBound(varValues, 2)
            If IsDate(varValues(lngColumns, lngRows)) Then
                dt = CDate(varValues(lngColumns, lngRows))
                dt = DateAdd("h", 1, dt)
                varValues(lngColumns, lngRows) = Format(dt, "mm/dd/yy h:nnam/pm")
            End If
        Next lngRows
    Next lngColumns

    'Overwrite usedRange with array
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange = varValues

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

This should be quiet performant regardless of the amount of data you're processing.
It goes without saying that this might not account for everything without having seen your workbook and has to be thoroughly tested.